# How to fix this error: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pygame

Line 34 is where the error apparently occurs, I'm a newbie to pygame so I don't actually know what's happening. The code is meant to perform a function once I click on an image. I also don't know if this works as this error is preventing me from knowing.

```
import pygame


black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
pygame.init()
size = (500, 400)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(150,450,100,50))
button1 = pygame.Rect(100,100,50,50)
button2 = pygame.Rect(200,200,50,50)
button3 = pygame.Rect(130,250,50,50)
pygame.display.set_caption("Yami no Game")

txt = pygame.image.load('txt.png')
Stxt = pygame.transform.scale(txt,(48,48))

exe = pygame.image.load('exe.jpg')
Sexe = pygame.transform.scale(exe,(48,48))
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_image=pygame.image.load('windows_background.jpg').convert()
 
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()   # position
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()  # left/right click
    if Sexe[100] + Sexe[48] > mouse[0] > Sexe[100] and Sexe[100] + Sexe(48) > mouse[1] > Sexe[100]:  # Mouse coordinates checking.
        if click[0] == 1: # Left click
            import The_Start #ignore this
    
    screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])
    screen.blit(Stxt,[100,100])
    screen.blit(Sexe,[250,250])

    pygame.display.update()
 

    clock.tick(60)
 

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to evaluate if the mouse is in the rectangular area, which is covered by the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object `Sexe`.
I recommend to get a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object by [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) form `Sexe`.
Use [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to check if the mouse is in the rectangular area.
Note, a Surface has no location, it *gets* a location when it is `blit`. Hence the location of the rectangle has to be set by an key word argument (`Sexe.get_rect(topleft = (250,250))`):

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    sexe_rect = Sexe.get_rect(topleft = (250, 250)) # position of Sexe as in blit(Sexe, [250,250])
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if sexe_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click[0] == 1:
            print("Clicked on Sexe")


    # [...]
    screen.blit(Sexe, [250,250])
    # [...]
```